# CSS animation using translateX instead of margin-left, is it possible?

Tags: html, css, animation, transform, margin

Recently I ran into the video demonstrating difference between margin and transform animations.
Unfortunately I can't remember video title or link. but basically it claimed that using `transform:translateX()` was way smoother than `margin-left`, especially on throttling mode.

I made an automatic slideshow with `margin-left`, and I'm trying to rewrite the animation using `translateX`, couldn't figure it out yet.
Any help will be appreciated.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#slides {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0;
}

#slidewrapper {
  width: calc(6 * 100vw);
  /* you need to use calc for math */
  animation: slide 26s ease infinite;
}

.slide {
  /* float: left; <- unnecessary */
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.landingphoto {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  object-fit: cover;
}

@keyframes slide {
  20% {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  30% {
    margin-left: -100%;
  }
  50% {
    margin-left: -100%;
  }
  60% {
    margin-left: -200%;
  }
  70% {
    margin-left: -200%;
  }
  80% {
    margin-left: -300%;
  }
  90% {
    margin-left: -300%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="slides">
  <div id="slidewrapper"></div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/ULmaQh9Gvbg/1600x900" class="landingphoto">
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/ggZuL3BTSJU/1600x900" class="landingphoto">
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/yXpA_eCbtzI/1600x900" class="landingphoto">
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/RyRpq9SUwAU/1600x900" class="landingphoto">
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/BeOW_PJjA0w/1600x900" class="landingphoto">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Don't use IDs, components are meant to be reusable. Use only Classes.
- Speaking or reusability, don't hardcode `animation` in CSS. If you add only one image or remove one, you'll find yourself in need to painfully modify the CSS to adjust for the problem. Use **JavaScript** instead (in combination with CSS `transform`)

```js
// Carousel (slides):

const carousel = (elCarousel) => {
  
  const timePause = 4000;
  const timeAnim = 1000;
  
  const elsSlides = elCarousel.children;
  const tot = elsSlides.length;
  let itv;
  let c = 0; // current slide index
  
  elCarousel.style.transition = `transform ${timeAnim}ms`;
  
  const anim = () => { elCarousel.style.transform = `translateX(${-c * 100}%)`; };
  const play = () => { itv = setInterval(next, timePause); };
  const stop = () => { clearInterval(itv); };
  const next = () => { c += 1;c %= tot; anim(); };
  
  play();
  
};

// Apply carousel to desired elements:
document.querySelectorAll(".slidesWrapper").forEach(carousel);
```

```css
/*QuickReset*/ * {margin:0; box-sizing: border-box;}

.slides {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slidesWrapper {
  display: flex;
}
.slide {
  position: relative;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  min-height: 200px;
}
.slide img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="slides">
  <div class="slidesWrapper">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/ULmaQh9Gvbg/1600x900" class="landingphoto">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/ggZuL3BTSJU/1600x900" class="landingphoto">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/yXpA_eCbtzI/1600x900" class="landingphoto">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/RyRpq9SUwAU/1600x900" class="landingphoto">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/BeOW_PJjA0w/1600x900" class="landingphoto">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

You can have as many carousels as you want!

<div class="slides">
  <div class="slidesWrapper">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/RyRpq9SUwAU/1600x900" class="landingphoto">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/yXpA_eCbtzI/1600x900" class="landingphoto">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/BeOW_PJjA0w/1600x900" class="landingphoto">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

PS: if you want to pause the animation on mouseenter and restart the animation on mouseleave simply add this two lines:

```js
elCarousel.addEventListener("pointerenter", stop);
elCarousel.addEventListener("pointerleave", play);
```

Comment: i dont know i have this feeling about css  only , as if its a challenge , but yeah javascript makes everything easier, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Here is my try, I have added some comments in the code

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#slides {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0;
}

#slidewrapper {
  width: calc(6 * 100vw);
  transition: all 2s; /* added this line */
}

.slide {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  animation: slide 16s ease infinite; /* move this line from #slidewrapper */
}

.landingphoto {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  object-fit: cover;
}

@keyframes slide {
  20% {
    transform: translateX(0); /* changed this line */
  }
  90% {
    transform: translateX(-400vw); /* changed this line */
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="slides">
            <div id="slidewrapper"></div>
                <div class="slide">
                    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/ULmaQh9Gvbg/1600x900"class="landingphoto">
                </div>
                <div class="slide">
                    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/ggZuL3BTSJU/1600x900" class="landingphoto">
                </div>
                <div class="slide">
                    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/yXpA_eCbtzI/1600x900" class="landingphoto">
                </div>
                <div class="slide">
                    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/RyRpq9SUwAU/1600x900" class="landingphoto">
                </div>
                <div class="slide">
                    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/BeOW_PJjA0w/1600x900" class="landingphoto">
                </div>
        </div>
```

is this what you mean? hope this help

Comment: Why do you use `-300vw` instead of `-400vw`? You have 5 images, not 4.

Comment: Dita, have you noticed an important detail in OP's example? The animation is supposed to pause between slides.

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem is that the wrapper element in fact does not wrap the slides, it comes just before them.

The given code works because it sets the margin of the wrapper negative so everything is displaced by that amount.

We can't just make the margin settings into transform translateX settings therefore.

Instead this snippet makes the wrapper wrap the slides. It sets it to flex so the slides sit alongside each other and then it translates itself by multiples of 100vw in the animation.

You are right that translate can be smoother than setting the margin and this seems to be born out when using the browser mobile emulator for example.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#slidewrapper {
  width: calc(6 * 100vw);
  /* you need to use calc for math */
  animation: slide 26s ease infinite;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.slide {
  /* float: left;  unnecessary */
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: inline-block;
}

.landingphoto {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  object-fit: cover;
}

@keyframes slide {
  20% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  30% {
    transform: translateX(-100vw);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(-100vw);
  }
  60% {
    transform: translateX(-200vw);
  }
  70% {
    transform: translateX(-200vw);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translateX(-300vw);
  }
  90% {
    transform: translateX(-300vw);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="slides">
  <div id="slidewrapper">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/ULmaQh9Gvbg/1600x900" class="landingphoto">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/ggZuL3BTSJU/1600x900" class="landingphoto">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/yXpA_eCbtzI/1600x900" class="landingphoto">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/RyRpq9SUwAU/1600x900" class="landingphoto">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/BeOW_PJjA0w/1600x900" class="landingphoto">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where's the 5th image? :) Also, the animation timings seem not well distributed.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan hi, I was seeking to emulate the effect that they currently have rather than correct other problems as the question was how to convert to translate from setting the margin. Yes, there are several other problems (including the strange rewinding at the end of the keyframes) but they were not covered in the question.

Comment: Also, the animation is supposed to be on the `#slidewrapper`, not on the `.slides` (which should be `overflow: hidden` BTW). Also IDs should not be used - for portability and reusability.

Comment: nice approach , animation is exactly the same as i had, but there is one problem it looses responsiveness, as soon as you change window size, but thanks for the info very helpful

Comment: I don't see a responsiveness problem, but maybe you wanted the whole image viewable whatever the aspect ratio of the viewport?

Comment: Incidentally, you can do the whole thing in CSS only, including making the slider continuous rather than 'rewinding' if needed if you are allowed to alter the HTML.